# Issue with raw SQL in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I use raw SQL to build an SQL editor in my project. But when I call simple select queries, I get this result:

```
[{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Ukraine", "phone_code"=>"+38", "created_at"=>"2015-11-23 21:52:49.415748", "updated_at"=>"2015-11-23 21:52:49.415748", 0=>1, 1=>"Ukraine", 2=>"+38", 3=>"2015-11-23 21:52:49.415748", 4=>"2015-11-23 21:52:49.415748"}]
```

The query is simple:

```
SELECT * FROM countries
```

As you can see, the same fields are displayed firstly with titles of attributes, and then second time with integer indexes.

I use this code two output only elements with attribute titles:

```
@headers = @result.first.keys
@count = @headers.size / 2
```

After that I iterate over headers:

```
<tr>
    <% (0...@count).each do |i| %>
        <th><%= @headers[i] %></th>
    <% end %>
</tr>
```

But I think that it is not the best solution. So, what is the best way to output only elements with proper titles, not with indexes?

Comment: How are you running the query?

Answer (score 0):

Try [select_all](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#select-all)

```
$ bin/rails c

Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.4)
>> result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all "SELECT * FROM wingnuts"
   (0.4ms)  SELECT * FROM wingnuts
=> #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x007fb92fbcdb18 @columns=["id", "size"], @rows=[[1, 10], [2, 11], [3, 12]], @hash_rows=nil, @column_types={}>
>> result.each { |row| puts row.inspect }
{"id"=>1, "size"=>10}
{"id"=>2, "size"=>11}
{"id"=>3, "size"=>12}
=> [{"id"=>1, "size"=>10}, {"id"=>2, "size"=>11}, {"id"=>3, "size"=>12}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the known keys that you want to extract from the hash, then you can just use [**Hash#select**](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) method as following:

```
a = [{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Ukraine", "phone_code"=>"+38", "created_at"=>"2015-11-23 21:52:49.415748", "updated_at"=>"2015-11-23 21:52:49.415748", 0=>1, 1=>"Ukraine", 2=>"+38", 3=>"2015-11-23 21:52:49.415748", 4=>"2015-11-23 21:52:49.415748"}]
known_keys = %w(id name phone_code created_at updated_at)
a[0].select { |key, value| known_keys.include? key }
# => {"id"=>1, "name"=>"Ukraine", "phone_code"=>"+38", "created_at"=>"2015-11-23 21:52:49.415748", "updated_at"=>"2015-11-23 21:52:49.415748"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are returning in this manner, but in answer to your question "what is the best way to output only elements with proper titles, not with indexes?":

```
# The new, properly formatted object
hash_of_proper_keys = Hash.new

# Assuming country is in the form of a hash of values
country.each do |key, value|
    hash_of_proper_keys[key] = value unless key.is_a? integer
end
```